# Controlling External Swf(Scenes, Frame) inside Main Swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, controls, external

Am gonna create an encyclopedia program, consist many of Chapter. I have difficulties about **controlling external swf inside my Main swf**. This is my Main.as in Actionscript 3

```
public class utama extends MovieClip {
 var loader:Loader;
 var urlReq:URLRequest;
 public function utama() {
 hal1.visible=true;
 hal2.visible=true;
 hal1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, keHal1);
 home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backHome);
 sebelum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevPage);
 sesudah.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextPage);
}

function prevPage(e:MouseEvent):void {
 //this is were I controlled the Prev page
 trace(parent.numChildren);   
}
function nextPage(e:MouseEvent):void {
 //this is were I controlled the Next page
}
function backHome(e:MouseEvent):void {
//If home button clicked then goes here
parent.removeChild(loader);
hal1.visible=true;
hal2.visible=true;
}
function keHal1(e:MouseEvent):void {
 //this is were I Load Page 1
 var url:String="./hal1.swf";
 urlReq=new URLRequest(url);
 loader=new Loader();
 loader.load(urlReq);

 parent.addChild(loader);

 hal1.visible=false;
 hal2.visible=false;
}
}
```

Am using eksternal page as a Chapter, and A Chapter consist of many Pages (it using Scene)
For an example :

Chapter 1 --> Page 1 it will be represented as hal1.swf-->Scene 1
Chapter 1 --> Page 2 it will be represented as hal1.swf-->Scene 2

Now, How to control it, I still didn't get it ??

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of swf after loading. If it is MovieClip, you can call gotoAndStop(frameNumber) from it to set current frame. If it is AVM1Movie, it is AS2 swf and you cannot control it.